# How to set hostname property as a DataSnapServer using firemonkey in delphi?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I am trying to reach database from DataSnap server by following embarcadero's mobile tutorial.Here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Connecting_to_an_Enterprise_Database_from_a_Mobile_Client_(iOS_and_Android)

But when ı try to set hostname of TSQLconnection component ı am facing this socket error."socket error #10061" ı have searched this error on this page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Briefly My dataSnapServer takes datas from databases but ı can not take datas from DataSnap Server.

Comment: You need to do some basic fault finding. Firstly, does your hostname resolve to the IP address of your server? Secondly, is there a firewall active on the server that is preventing the connection? Thirdly is your data snap server actually running? All of this could be found out in less time than it took you to compose and post your question.